# Trying to pass a parameter to procedure but getting an exception thrown?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I would like to pass an 'inputCounter' parameter by pushing it onto the stack. Within the procedure, I dereferenced the stack pointer pointing to this parameter, and would like to add it to the address of array and then increment it by 4 (size of the array) However, I am getting an error of:

Exception thrown at 0x00403729 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0080C0ED.

I am using Visual Studio and the irvine32.inc library.

I've tried debugging ebx (the register I hold my inputCounter in) and in the first run through I expect it to be 0 and then the second run, I expect it to be 4. However, it starts at 0 (which was defined in my main) but then it jumps to '0040607B' for some reason. And the error occurs with the line:

mov [esi], eax.

Help would be much appreciated!

```
include Irvine32.inc

.data
array   dword 2 DUP (?)
inputCounter dword 0

.code
main proc
    mov esi, offset array
    mov ecx, lengthof array + 1
    mov ebx, 0

    loopMain:
        push offset inputCounter ;push the address of inputCounter onto the stack
        call input
        push offset inputCounter ;push the address of inputCounter onto the stack
        call input
    loop loopMain
    exit
main endp

input proc
    pushad                           ;save all registers
    mov ebx, [esp + 36]              ;store inputCounter into ebx
    mov edx, offset prompt           ;address of the prompt

    call writeString
    call readInt
    add esi, ebx                     ;add 'inputCounter' to address of array
    mov [esi], eax                   ;*error occurs here*
    add dword ptr[ebx], 4            ;increment 'inputCounter' by 4 (size of array)

    popad                            ;restore all registers
    ret
input endp
end main
```

Comment: By using the `offset` keyword you told the assembler that you wanted to place _the address of_ `inputCounter` on the stack, so it does. Then you add that address and the address of `array` and try to write to the resulting address.

Comment: But doesn't `mov ebx, [esp + 36]` dereference the `inputCounter` address and then store the actual value into `ebx`? @Michael

Comment: No. That just gives you whatever value happens to be stored at `esp+36`. And that value in this case is the address of `inputCounter`.

Comment: What you're doing is essentially the same as if you had passed an `int*` to a function in C and then tried to get the `int` value by casting the pointer to an `int` instead of dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. So I have to dereference `ebx` again since `[esp + 36]` is the address of `inputCounter`?

Comment: If you want the value instead of the address, yes.

Comment: Thank you Michael.